# Draw a bitmap C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to draw an image on the screen with bitmap class but something is wrong.

Here is my code:

```
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(@"C:\Alan\University\111.jpg");
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
g.DrawImage(bm,60,60);
```

after running the code nothing append on my screen.
what is wrong in my code?
thanks

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! As we find ourselves saying to a lot of newcomers - "something is wrong" is not a valid description of a problem. **What** is wrong? What do you expect? What happens? Elaborate. =)

Answer (score 7):

You're making a graphics object from the `Image` itself and then you try to draw the image onto itself. You need to draw the image into another `Graphics` object. Typically something representing the screen or the component where you want the image displayed.

You don't specify in what sort of context you try to draw the image in. How to get the `Graphics` object depends on the framework (WPF, WinForms etc). For a typical winforms application you want to override `OnPaint` in your window like this:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
   Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(@"C:\Alan\University\111.jpg");

   // Draw using this   
   e.Graphics.DrawImage(bm,60,60);

   base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

Of course, you would want to load the image only once at some startup method and not every time you draw the form.

Comment: thanks for trying helping me.
but in my win forms project, the e argument does not have an option e.Graphics. i understand that i need something to represent my screen, how can i represent it?

Comment: You didn't specify Winforms, but I added a sample for you overriding the `OnPaint` on a `Form`

Comment: i still have a problem with the "PaintEventArgs e".
from where i get it? in my code, the main receive 2 arguments:"object sender, EventArgs e", so from where i receive the "PaintEventArgs e"?

Comment: In order to help you you need to show more code. The sample you have provided is not enough to see the entire problem. If you provide a complete working sample of code it's much easier to see where you go wrong. To get a hold of `PaintEventArgs` you make an override of a `OnPaint` method inside your component or form.

Comment: thank you very much, its working. i found the problem. you helped a lot!!!

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it helped you. Click the little checkmark next to the question to mark it as the accepted answer.